# Symfony2: add routes from my bundle

Tags: symfony, routes

I created a bundle `wjb/ImageBundle` but I would like to load its routes without modifying `app/config/routing.yml`. From FOSRestBundle and few more, I see it is possible but I coudn't figure a way how to do that.

Is there some idiot-proof tutorial? I would like to use annotations but I would accept any other way too.

Answer (score 4):

**It's not possible to have routes in your application without registering them.**

FOSUserBundle's routes can partly be defined in your security.firewalls configuration.

The others have  to be imported as well described in the documentation chapter #6 - [FOSUserbundle import routing files](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md#step-6-import-fosuserbundle-routing-files).

A workaround may be adding routes when loading a bundle without touching your routing.yml in a [CompilerPass](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/service_container/compiler_passes.html).